# Mostrar datos en firebase

Tags: firebase, listview

Necesito ayuda , lo que sucede es que tengo esta estructura en firebase y quiero mostrarlo en un listview en android studio , quiero que muestre los datos que estan marcados todo en un listview [image: Estructura de firebase]

Comment: Añade un poco del código que has intentado. Aparte te recomiendo buscar en la documentación oficial de google, que es muy completa.

Comment: En que lenguaje esta programado ? tienes una clase objeto para esos datos ?